# underline line thickness always one pixel

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

...regardless of font size.

Its an mx:Text object.  (The Text  object is actually being used as a mask so don't know if that's the problem.)  If underline is set with the `<u>` tag in Text.htmlText, or Text.textField.setTextFormat,  the underline thickness is always just one pixel which is not acceptable. (There are other problems with `<u>` so I'm limited to using setTextFormat currently.)

Can the thickness of an underline be set through CSS? (textField.styleSheet, etc.)

I may have another problem as I already  use setTextFormat extensively, and the documentation  says you can't use textField.setTextFormat if you use textField.setStyleSheet.

I primarily need the underline to simulate correctly the look for an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

its not even possible to do in html (you need to use border-bottom). [i don't think this is possible](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002174.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with CSS or TextFormat.
A possible workaround would be using the textfield metrics (probably through [getCharBoundaries()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharBoundaries%28%29)) to manually draw a line under the desired text. It can get quite messy for multiline text though.

Comment: I probably will go this route if you're sure it can't be done through CSS (through border-bottom, for example as described above)